# How to put a variable in the id inside the html tag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, ejs

I am wondering how to put a variable in the id inside the html tag.
I came across this issue while implementing pagination.
Like that picture, I want the i+1 part of the value of id="page-box-i+1" to be replaced with an actual number, not a string.
For example, if i is 2, I want it to be id="page-box-3".
How can it be solved? I am implementing it in an vue.js & ejs file.

[image]

Comment: `id="page-box-<%= i + 1 =>"`

Comment: i did
id="page-box-<%= i + 1 =>" 
and also 
id="page-box-<%= i + 1 %> " 
, but it didn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Use v-bind attribute:

```html
<div v-bind:id="'page-box-' + (i + 1)"></div>
```